# Swap out prev() or next() depending on direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the right function depending on what I choose.
Example code:

```
function move(direction){
    if (direction == 'next'){
        $(selector).someMethod().next().someMethod();
    }
    if (direction == 'back'){
        $(selector).someMethod().prev().someMethod();
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Trying to not duplice code when the only thing that changes is that single method.

Comment: Something like `var method = direction === 'next' ? 'next' : 'prev'; $(selector).someMethod()[method]().someMethod()`.

Comment: Just separate the steps. `var foo = $(selector).someMethod(); if (direction == "back") { foo = foo.prev(); } else { foo = foo.next(); } foo.someMethod();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation - pass the method name as an argument to `move`, validate that it is in fact one of the allowed methods, then proceed as normal.

```
function move(direction){
    if (direction.search(/next|prev/) === -1) {
        console.log('invalid direction');
        return;
    }
    $(selector).someMethod()[direction]().someMethod();
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Works 100% Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Take the steps that don't change at all, remove them to outside the conditional, and store what you need from the conditional in a variable.

```
function move(direction) {
    var element = $(selector);
    var otherElement;

    if (direction === "next") {
        otherElement = element.next();
    }
    else if(direction === "back") {
        otherElement = element.prev();
    }

    element.someMethod();
    otherElement.someMethod();
}
```

A note: where does `selector` come from? Consider passing it into your function as a parameter, if it's not constant.

---

If you want this to be even more extensible, so that you're not limited to just `next` and `prev` but can use any selector or set of methods you like, then you could define a dictionary with the direction names and a function that returns the other element:

```
var elementsInDirection = {
    "next": function(elem) { return elem.next(); },
    "back": function(elem) { return elem.prev(); },
    "up": function(elem) { return elem.parent(); },
    "down": function(elem) { return elem.children(); }
};

function move(direction) {
    var element = $(selector);
    var otherElement = elementsInDirection[direction](element);

    element.someMethod();
    if(otherElement) otherElement.someMethod();
}
```

Now you could have `move("up")` or `move("down")` or anything else you care to define.